# Gulp - Error Causing Task to Stop

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify

I'm setting up a project using Gulp along with Browserify but I'm having a little trouble with getting the watch command to catch errors and keep on watching.

I run a 'gulp' command using the default task (code below). This task sets up using watch to catch any changes in my files, then compiles my js using Browserify and also compiles my scss files.

All goes well unless I make a syntax error in my js. Basically, if that happens the console shows the error but ceases to catch anymore changes to my js files.

I had originally omitted the error handling which was causing the whole watch task to fail but now I have that in there - the watch task is still going and it works just fine for my scss (even if I make a syntax error) but it won't catch any changes at all to my js.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp'),
    gutil       = require('gulp-util'),
    browserify  = require('browserify'),
    changed     = require('gulp-changed'),
    compass     = require('gulp-compass'),
    uglify      = require('gulp-uglify'),
    livereload  = require('gulp-livereload'),
    transform   = require('vinyl-transform'),
    sassSources = ['_src/sass/**/*.scss'],
    jsSources   = ['_src/js/admin.js', '_src/js/main.js'];

var onError = function (err) {
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.green(err));
};

gulp.task('js', function() {

    var browserified = transform(function(filename) {
        var b = browserify(filename);
        return b.bundle();
    });

    return gulp.src(jsSources)
        .pipe(browserified)
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'))

});

gulp.task('js-dev', function() {

    var browserified = transform(function(filename) {
        var b = browserify(filename);
        return b.bundle();
    });

    return gulp.src(jsSources)
        .pipe(browserified)
            .on('error', onError)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'))
        .pipe(livereload())

});

gulp.task('sass', function() {

    gulp.src(sassSources)
        .pipe(compass({
            style: 'compressed',
            sass: '_src/sass',
            css: 'assets/css',
            font: 'assets/fonts',
            image: 'assets/images',
            javascript: 'assets/js',
            relative: true,
            require: ['breakpoint']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))

});

gulp.task('sass-dev', function() {

    gulp.src(sassSources)
        .pipe(changed('assets/css'))
        .pipe(compass({
            style: 'expanded',
            sass: '_src/sass',
            css: 'assets/css',
            font: 'assets/fonts',
            image: 'assets/images',
            javascript: 'assets/js',
            relative: true,
            require: ['breakpoint']
        }))
            .on('error', onError)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
        .pipe(livereload())

});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    livereload.listen()
    gulp.watch(jsSources, ['js-dev'])
    gulp.watch(sassSources, ['sass-dev'])
    gulp.watch(['**/*.php']).on('change', function(file) { livereload.changed(file.path) })
})

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'js-dev', 'sass-dev'])
gulp.task('build', ['js', 'sass'])
```

The above code is my entire gulpfile but the task I'm testing is the default task - and the task handling the js is the 'js-dev' task.

Why would my code cause the js-dev task to fail when my sass-dev task with the same error handling doesn't?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a guess, but the error handler may need to emit an event:

```
var onError = function ( err ) {
  gutil.log( gutil.colors.green( err.message ) );
  this.emit( 'end' );
};
```

Stolen from my own `gulp.js` which handles browserified in the same way.